# I am writing a pretty simple iPhone app that will play a sound depending on which button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A... as I learn Objective C.

There will be close to 20 button on a view at a time... :)

If I use a if/else loop for each button touched,  it works great but I consider that to be inelegant and just plain cumbersome.

SO, I am using the button.tag to allow me to assign a number to each button then evaluate each button based on the .tag property.
As I mentioned before, works great with if/else if loops.

But I want to change the tag to a string and then nest it within a NSURL to play a sound.  Each button will generate a new tag and consequently a new sound.

As reported by the debugger, I am getting Not a CFSTRING and 'out of bounds' messages and upon stepping through, crashes.  Fun, but not blue screen.

Here is the code in question.  I humbly request of the Objective C gurus to lend some insight!

```
int soundNumber = [sender tag];

//soundPick = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", soundNumber]; //remmed out as an alternative try
NSString *soundPick = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:soundNumber] stringValue];

NSURL *aSoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:soundPick ofType:@"aif"]];   
playSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aSoundURL error:&error];
if (!playSound) {
    NSLog(@"no Sound for that button: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
} 
[playSound play];

*/
```

Thanks,

Neil

Comment: Shoudn't you replace "mainBundle" by "[NSBundle mainBundle]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an array with all 20 file paths in it, then i would use the tag to index the array.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you're programming behaviour in your buttons.

Why don't you just assign each button to a different IBOutlet/callback method? You won't need any if/else statements at all.

Comment: You can even map them all to the *same* action method that builds the resource name dynamically based on properties of the sender, since you can get the sender object as an id in the method call.

Comment: You can, sure. Is that level of complexity required, all for the sake of using just a single action method?

Comment: Well, if it's just "button A plays sound A", that seems pretty simple.

Comment: I guess we see simple in different ways. To me, using tags + a switch statement (which creates a long method body) is not as simple (readable) as having one action method per button.

Comment: @yehnan - I didn't copy the entire code stream.  However, it is declared;thanks though.

@Shaggyfrog - If I understand you correctly, I could create a 1 buton to one sound relationship, but if I have 20 or more buttons, that is tedious to maintain.

@Joe - that is exactly what I wish to do.. But I am using the button.tag property.  However, I am having troubles evaluating the .tag datum.  The sender info is type .id - how do I incorporate that information into the NSURL method I have illustrated?

Thanks again! You guys rock

Answer (score 0):

On your IBActions, add something like this:

```
SystemSoundID theSound; 
NSString *pathToSound;

pathToSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<filename>" ofType:@"<filetype>"] isDirectory:NO];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)pathToSound, &theSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (theSound);
```

Then add this to your .h file and the the AudioToolbox.framework to your project:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Worked like a charm for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I got the code to work and I used the button.tag. Then, I named each sound file against the tag number..

So, tag 1 = 1.aif, tag 2=2.aif etc...  I used a paper chart to get started then off to the races.

THe issue I had was how to get the button.tag as a string and I struggled until I figured it out:

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
int soundTag = [sender tag];
soundPick = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", soundTag];

Then took soundPick and stuck in the appropriate location in NSURL..   
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! I got the code to work and I used the button.tag. Then, I named each sound file against the tag number.. So, tag 1 = 1.aif, tag 2=2.aif etc... I used a paper chart to get started then off to the races. THe issue I had was how to get the button.tag as a string and I struggled until I figured it out: -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender; int soundTag = [sender tag]; soundPick = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", soundTag]; Then took soundPick and stuck in the appropriate location in NSURL.. Thanks!

Comment: you should have put this in your post and marked this question as answered